# posterior distribution given parametrization of prior parameters

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, gamma-function, bayesian, gamma-distribution

we set our distribution to be f(x|u,p)=$\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{\frac{p}{2\pi}}exp[-\frac{p}{2\pi}(ln(x)-u)^2]$ with p>0,u=0 we consider n observations from $x_1...x_n$, p is unknown and we asssume a prior $Gamma(\frac{\alpha}{2},\frac{\beta}{2})$ on p

if we parametrize $\alpha=ab$  and $\beta=b$
a and b unknown, what is the posterior if we assume Gamma(1,2) hyperpriors for both parameters?

My strategy would be computing a $Gamma(\frac{ab}{2},\frac{b}{2})$ prior with the above likelihood and then multiplying it by both of the hyperpriors but my cancellation seems to be off im struggling to find the posterior distribution.

Comment: Looks again to be a gamma if you bring the $p^{n/2}$ together with the $p^{ab/2 - 1}$ term from the prior, and also the exponential terms: $e^{-\frac{p}{2\pi}\sum(\ln(x_i)-u)^2}e^{-\frac{2p}{b}}$. ($u=0$)

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst oh okay so its the same strategy and we we still keep the p terms while ignoring all of the extra hyper prior terms?

Comment: pretty much yeah, it comes together nice when you just imagine all the $x$, $u$ terms are just some factor, same as in all bayesian problems